# downloading multiple parameters with get_gfs.pl partial gfs download

Tags: cmd, noaa

I tried to run the following in cmd:

```
perl get_gfs.pl data 2021041900 0 6 3 "TMAX.2 m|TMIN.2 m" .
```

However it doesn't return any data. If I only pass one parameter, for example:

```
perl get_gfs.pl data 2021041900 0 6 3 TMAX.2 m .
```

it works well.

Example and download script taken from here: https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/get_gfs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over the linked script, it looks like the single variable command:

```
perl get_gfs.pl data 2021041900 0 6 3 TMAX.2 m .
```

isn't quite right.

Running that seems to download the inventory files only (`.tmp` files), and that the correct invocation should be something like:

```
perl get_gfs.pl data 2021041900 0 6 3 TMAX "2 m" .
```

separating the variable list (`TMAX`) from the levels list (`2 m`, which matches `2 m above ground`).

So, modifying that for the multiple variable case, you would run:

```
perl get_gfs.pl data 2021041900 0 6 3 TMAX:TMIN "2 m" .
```

The use of `:` instead of `|` is based on the documentation at the top of the script; internally it replaces `:` with `|` before using the regex, but it seems prudent to respect what the script says it expects.

In any case, running either of those commands downloads 2 files fully, both of which are identified as:

```
Gridded binary (GRIB) version 2
```

and with the second `TMAX:TMIN` case the files are approximately twice as big, seemingly indicating that they contain all the additional data.